# My loop is only returning one value

Tags: php

The issue here is that when I do print_r after I create the array with `$picnameoutput` it prints the array as you will see in the screenshot.

Later after I run the for loop and echo it just to see the output it only gives me 1 value and I can't figure out why it picks that value, it is not even the first one in the array.

Very Frustrated.

Here is my code

```
<?php
  $largedir = 'images/headshots/large';
  $large = scandir($largedir);

  $picnameoutput = preg_grep("/adam.*/", $large); 
  print_r($picnameoutput);

  for ($i=0; $i<count($picnameoutput); $i++); {
  echo "$picnameoutput[$i]";
  }
?>
```

And here is a screenshot so you can see what I mean

[image]

Comment: Replace $i < count($picnameoutput) by $i <= count($picnameoutput) to loop through all the values. You are getting adam8.jpg because of the syntax you used.

Comment: You should never use `count()` in a loop since it would be executed on every loop. You should just add the value of `count()` to a variable and check on that variable in your loop.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have a semicolon `;` after `for()` before bracket. Remove it.

So

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($picnameoutput); $i++); {
echo "$picnameoutput[$i]";
}
```

becomes

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($picnameoutput); $i++) {
    echo "$picnameoutput[$i]";
}
```

however I would recommend to use [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) instead

```
foreach ($picnameoutput as $pic) {
    echo $pic;
}
```

which is pretty easy to use and even faster than your for loop

Comment: That's awesome, now I have another question for you, Why does that work better? When I was using just "for" it was returning the first 2 values of the array as non existent but using for each fixed that right up!

Comment: @GrooveChampion: because there are some indexes missing (as 1 and 2)

Answer (score 12):

You have a semi-colon after the `for`, so your code is executed like:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($picnameoutput); $i++) {
   ; // Do nothing
}
{
  echo "$picnameoutput[$i]";
}
```

Also, it could be written shorter as

```
echo implode('', glob('images/headshots/large/adam*'));
```

Comment: This is one of my first attempts, it has taken me a long time to get this far... I do appreciate the advice though thanks.

Comment: @GrooveChampion Don't worry, that's a typical, even textbook mistake. For one of the first attempts, your code looks remarkably good. Don't take my one-liner too serious ;).

Comment: Yeah it took me a bit to find out about the regular expressions and took a lot of thinking to figure this out but I wanted to force myself to do it since the books I have been using don't really make you do anything... For me it is hard to take in so much theory without doing anything...